# Images loading in incorrectly even with cache

Tags: ios, swift, caching

```
 if let toID = message.chatPartnerId() {
        firebaseReference.child(toID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {


            cell.nameLabel.text = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
            let pic = dictionary["pictureURL"] as! String
                print("THIS IS THE URL FOR EACH DISPLAYNAME")
                print(dictionary["displayname"] as? String)
                print(pic)


                if let imageFromCache = MainPageVC.imageCache.object(forKey: pic as NSString) {

                    cell.pictureLabel.image = imageFromCache
                } else {

                    let requested = URLRequest(url: URL(string: pic )!)

                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requested) {data, response, err in


                        if err != nil {
                            print(err)
                        } else {

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                      MainPageVC.imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: pic as NSString)
                                //cell.pictureLabel.image = nil
                                cell.pictureLabel.image = imageToCache

                            }
                        }

                        }.resume()
                } 
            }
        })
    }


    return cell
}
```

I'm running this code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I'm getting a ton of really bad behavior. I'm also getting similar behavior on other pages but for some reason this block of code with about a 90% consistency returns incorrect information for cells.

I get a lot of duplicate pictures being used, `displaynames` in the wrong places, but when I'm actually clicking into a person, my detail page shows the correct information every single time. That code is the typical `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and passing the person.

What I don't understand is why on the initial load of this page all of the information is screwed up, but if I click into someone and come back the entire `tableview` has correct names and pictures. The names/pics also fix if I scroll a cell off the screen then come back to it.

I'm getting this behavior all over my app, meanwhile I see caching/loading done like this everywhere. Is it because I'm running the code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? The only difference I see is that I'm running it there instead of creating a function inside of my Person class that configures cells and running it like that. What I don't understand is why that would make a difference because as far as I'm aware running a function within `cellforRowAtIndexpath` would be the same as copy-pasting that same code into there?

Any ideas/suggestions?

Edit: I'm getting a very similar situation when I'm running the following code:

```
self.PersonalSearchesList = self.PersonalSearchesList.sorted{ $0.users > $1.users }

self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Where I'm sorting my array before reloading my data. The information sometimes loads in incorrectly at first, but once I scroll the cell off the screen then come back to it it always corrects itself.

Comment: Clear the cell image in prepare for reuse, also try setting the image in willDisplayCell.

Comment: I hadn't seen prepareForReuse before, so I did a test "this is being called" and set the picture to nil. I haven't yet set the picture in willDisplayCell, but my array is 6 people long, but I'm getting the "this is being called" print out about 20 times in the console. If my array is 6 people long that should only be called 6 times yeah? Maybe thats a hint to what's going on. I am pulling from firebase though so maybe that makes sense as it'd be called for the item 1..then for item 1 and 2 and then for 1 2 and 3 and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting the same issue with those suggestions unfortunately.

Comment: As you scroll cells will be reused, so the functions can be called multiple times. Have a look at something like sdWbImage to load and cache your images

Comment: @paulw11 Yeah after looking at it more I think I might have misnamed my question a bit. I thought I was only getting incorrect images but I'm also getting incorrect UILabel text. 

If I'm also getting incorrect label text that would indicate that it's not an issue with my image caching system so something like Alamofire wouldn't fix it?

It's just weird to me that with 100% consistancy if I scroll off and back onto a cell the correct information is loaded into it but on first load it's messed up.

Comment: reloadData is costly operation as it will redraw the cell from the scratch. You are calling this method unnecessarily. One of the approach would be to capture the index.row of the cell. If this cell exist in view, then assign the image otherwise just cache the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using swift 3 here are some handy functions that allow you to save an image to your apps directory from an URL and then access it from anywhere in the app:

```
func saveCurrentUserImage(toDirectory urlString:String?) {
    if urlString != nil {
        let imgURL: URL = URL(string: urlString!)!
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgURL)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil) {
                func display_image() {
                    let userImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                    if let userImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImage!) {
                        let filename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("userImage")
                        try? userImageData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filename), options: [.atomic])
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: display_image)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and then access it with any view controller using this:

```
 extension UIViewController {

    func getImage(withName name: String) -> UIImage {
        let readPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(name)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath)
        return image!

    }
}
```

and finally calling it like this:

```
cell.pictureLabel.image = getImage(withName: "userImage")
```

If you can run the `saveCurrentUserImage` function prior to running `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then you can just check if the photo is nil in the directory before attempting to download it. You might be getting funny behavior when the page initially loads because you have multiple network calls going on at once. I wouldn't recommend making any network calls in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because every time the cells are re-initialized it's going to make that network call for each cell.

Hope it helps!

> EDIT: This method of image saving and retrieval is for images that you want to persist. If you want to erase them from memory you'll have to delete them from your directory.